# Passing array of record to delphi dll

Tags: arrays, delphi, dll, record

Is it possible to pass an array of record to dll (delphi)?

I have a record that I put in a shared (used in dll and main apps) delphi unit

```
TmyRecord = record
  tgl  : Double;
  notes: shortstring;
end

TarrOfMyRecord = array[1..1000] of TmyRecord
```

In the dll, I have a function:

```
function getNotes(var someRecord: TArrOfMyRecord):boolean; stdcall;
begin
  someRecord[1].tgl:= now;
  someRecord[1].notes:= 'percobaan';

  someRecord[2].tgl:= now + 1;
  someRecord[2].notes:= 'percobaan1';

  return:= true;
end;
```

I can't get the right values of someRecord returned by dll.

Thanks

UPDATE:
This is my code in main apps:

```
interface

function getNotes(var someRecord: TArrOfMyRecord):boolean; stdcall; external 'some.dll'

implementation

procedure somefunction;
var myRecord: TarrOfMyRecord;
    i: integer;
begin
  if getNotes(myRecord) then
      for i:= 1 to 1000 do memo1.lines.add(myRecord[i].notes);

end;
```

Comment: Show the code that calls the dll. Also, are you aware that you current approach commits all users of the DLL to be written in Delphi? Are you happy with that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes.. I'm aware about that and that's okay.

Comment: Your function define as getNotes(var someRecord: TArrOfMyRecord) but you pass the variable myRecord: TmyRecord?  Is this a Typo?

Comment: Please show us the real code. Showing us made up code does not help. The real code compiles. This does not. Also show how you import the function.

Comment: @Justmade: Ups.. sorry. I've fix it. thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sorry but the real code is big and I just want to know if I can pass the variable array of record to dll. thanks.

Comment: The code you have shown works, assuming you fix the compilation errors (`return := True` is not correct). I can only assume that this is not the code that is actually running. Now, obviously you can't show the entire code. But cut it down to a simple example that demonstrates the issue. This is still not the real code and you are just wasting our time. Please make more effort.

Comment: Could this be an indexing issue? What happens if you define TArrOfMyRecord as [0..10000] instead?

Comment: @rob no, that won't change things

Comment: In the main app, shouldn't you pass the first array entry( so: 'myRecord[Low(myRecord)]') instead of 'myRecord' as parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass huge amount of data to a DLL is using pointer.

The record definitions:

```
...
TarrOfMyRecord = array[1..1000] of TmyRecord
ParrOfMyRecord = ^TarrOfMyRecord;
```

DLL:

```
function getNotes(someRecord: PArrOfMyRecord):boolean; stdcall;
begin
  someRecord^[1].tgl:= now;
...
```

Program:

```
...
begin
  if getNotes(@myRecord) then
      for i:= 1 to 1000 do memo1.lines.add(myRecord[i].notes);
...
```

Comment: In this way I can use a only Delphi application or I call the DLL with other languages?

Comment: @Martin This method can be used among any program that is made by any programming language. Some Windows API functions use this method too.

Comment: If I try to use your code I get an error on "if getNotes(@myRecord)" because "the function must be have the some parameter"...

Comment: @Martin Did you define DLL function in your program interface? function getNotes(someRecord: PArrOfMyRecord):boolean; stdcall; external 'dllfilename.dll';